# Mailkit does not contain a definition for Security

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit

i have this line of code that give me an error:

```
smtpClient.Connect(host, port, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.None);
```

The error says "Mailkit does not contain a definition for Security", I'm missing some installation or what can it be? thx

Comment: check your project references. did you properly have a reference to MailKit library or not

Comment: @Nitz Yes, im even able to use some other mailkit functions, that one its the only one not working

Comment: What is the namespace of your project? Did you use "MailKit" as your project namespace?